# Função não deleta as pastas existentes dentro do diretório - FTP

Tags: php

Olá, estou com alguns problemas usando conexão FTP no PHP.

```
$ftp_server = "IPFTP";

    $dir = 'web/'.$server['siteurl'].'/templates/Fenix';
    $conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);
    $login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $username_v, $password_v);

    if (!(@ftp_rmdir($conn_id, $dir) || @ftp_delete($conn_id, $dir))) {

        $filelist = @ftp_nlist($conn_id, $dir);
        foreach ($filelist as $file) {
            @ftp_delete($conn_id, $file);
        }
    }
```

Gostaria de deletar todas as pastas/arquivos localizados dentro da pasta definida pela variável **dir**.
Sei que para usar a função é necessário que o diretório esteja vazio, por isso a função acima.

**Retorna:**

> Warning: ftp_rmdir(): Remove directory operation failed. in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\fpanel\change-theme.php on line 54

Comment: vc colocou !@ftp_rmdir, sendo que o @ verifica se aquilo vai ser atendido ou não... creio que não precise do @

Comment: `Warning: ftp_rmdir(): Remove directory operation failed. in C:\xampp\htdocs\fpanel\change-theme.php on line 45

Warning: ftp_delete(): Delete operation failed. in C:\xampp\htdocs\fpanel\change-theme.php on line 45

Warning: ftp_delete(): Delete operation failed. in C:\xampp\htdocs\fpanel\change-theme.php on line 49`

Novos erros retornados.